# How to remove HTML tags from Atom Feed XML

Tags: php, regex, xml, laravel

I prepared an XML feed for my  Laravel based blog. When I check it my feeds using feedvalidator. I am getting an error about youtube embedded videos :

```
line 24, column 0: content should not contain iframe tag (8 occurrences) [help]
```

I get my feeds in a controller :

```
public function index()
{   

    $data['posts'] = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->->where('status',,1)-->limit(20)->get();


    return Response::view('rss',$data, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8 ',
    ]);
}
```

My feed xml view is :

```
{{ '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' }}
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://sirtcantalilar.com/feed" />
    <title>Sirtcantalilar Topluluğu</title>
    <subtitle>Üzerinde Güneş Batmayan Topluluk</subtitle>
    <updated>{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->toATOMString() }}</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Sırtçantalılar</name>
    </author>
    <id>tag:sirtcantalilar.com,{{date('Y-m-d')}}:/{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->toATOMString() }}</id>

    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <entry>
            <author>
                <name>{{$post->author->name}}</name>
            </author>
            <title>{{ $post->title }}</title>
            <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="{{ URL::route('view-post', $post->slug) }}"/>
            <updated>{{$post->created_at->toATOMString() }}</updated>
            <id>{{ post_tag_uri($post)}}</id>
            @if(strlen($post->minicontent) > 0)
            <summary>{{$post->minicontent }}</summary>
            @else
            <summary>{{ Str::words(strip_tags(preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$post->content)),13)}}</summary>
            @endif
            <content type="html"><![CDATA[{{$post->content}}]]></content>
             <category term="Blog"/>
              <content type="html"><{{nl2br($post->content)}}></content>
     </entry>
    @endforeach

</feed>
```

How can I remove iframes from the content ?
edit 1 : I added this function :

```
function rss_noiframe($content) {
    $content = preg_replace( '/<iframe(.*)\/iframe>/is', '', $content );

    return $content;
}
```

and try to get the view :

```
<content type="html"><![CDATA[{{rss_noiframe($post->content)}}]]></content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would like an answer from this question I solved with the following code:

```
<content type="html"><![CDATA[{{preg_replace( '/<iframe(.*)\/iframe>/is', '', $post->content )}}]]></content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a short idea, how about reading your Content Tag's CData

```
   content type="html"><![CDATA[{{$post->content}}]]></content>
```

into an HTML Parser like [PHP HTMLSimple](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

```
$ret = $html->find('iframe');
```

Then drop the elements in $ret.

(Sorry, i have no php workenviroment here, so I can just give you an abstract theory of doing it)
I think this would get you further and safer than just using regex.

Comment: well i gess editing out whole text may be dangerous to the validity of the html structure. you should think about doing it inside of an DOM-Structure, as its more reliable. If you really really really want to do it with regex, be sure to set it to an ungreedy mode, as if you got <iframe>1</iframe>somerandomtext<iframe>2</iframe> might kill "somerandomtext" but thats not what you want